# Method has incorrect signature?

Tags: android

I am a beginner.
   The codes run only at android 6 and upper.
The code runs fine with 6 warning but i want to get rid of these 6 warning in the Menu_Main.xml 6 lines for example a line with onClick=itemClick.

What can i do to get rid of these warnings?Please help me.

### MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.sky.my13application;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }  
    public boolean itemClick(MenuItem item){
        Toast.makeText(this,item.getTitle() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }
}
```

### activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.sky.my13application.MainActivity">

</RelativeLayout>
```

### menu_Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

       <item android:title="@string/app_name1"
             android:onClick="itemClick"
             />
       <item android:title="@string/app_name2"
             android:onClick="itemClick"
             />
       <item android:title="@string/app_name3"
             android:onClick="itemClick"
             >
       <menu>
            <item android:title="@string/app_name4"
                  android:onClick="itemClick"
            />
            <item android:title="@string/app_name5"
                  android:onClick="itemClick"
             />
       </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

### strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My13Application</string>
    <string name="app_name1">item1</string>
    <string name="app_name2">item2</string>
    <string name="app_name3">sub menu</string>
    <string name="app_name4">sub item1</string>
    <string name="app_name5">sub item2</string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think relying on the `onClick` attribute is appropriate if you are in a menu (but maybe I'm wrong).

Anyway, you should remove your `onClick` attributes in XML and rely on [onOptionsItemSelected](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html])

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            action1();
            return true;
        case R.id.button2:
            action2();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```